# Drop pin in Mapview issue in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

```
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Above code works fine till iOS 8.
in ios 8 drop pin is not displaying in mapview .
Yes ios target is ios 7 and higher.
I also try several method but not working.

Any solutions ?

Comment: why are you calling startUpdatingLocation method twice.?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before. There's a location authorization issue due to core location manager changes in iOS8. Try adding this below code before calling startUpdatingLocation:

```
    if ([self._locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) 
    {
        [self._locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES; //optional
```

Prior to this, please make sure you add one or both of the following keys to your **Info.plist** file:

- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription